# Using multiple search parameters on a Grid field

Tags: channel-entries, search, grid

I am using search tag for express engine channel but it is not working.

for eg. I have created a channel named as 'XYZ'  and having following channel fields there :

1) user_type : text

2) profile : grid
        a) first_name : text 
        b) last_name :  text
        c) user_name : text 
        d) age : text

Now i want to show user listing for a entry which age is greater than 20 and less than 40. i have used following code :

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="xyz" entry_id=1}
    {profile search:age=">20" search:age="<40"}
        {profile:first_name}<br/>
        {profile:last_name}<br/>
        {profile:user_name}<br/>
        {profile:age}<hr>
    {/profile}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But the code above does not give correct result.

Please help me what is missing/wrong here or give me a solution for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use more than one search parameter per field.

Less than ideal, but you could do a conditional in addition to your search. It will throw you off if you want to use the `row_count` and `total_rows` variables though.

```
{profile search:age=">20"}
    {if age < 40}
        {profile:first_name}<br/>
        {profile:last_name}<br/>
        {profile:user_name}<br/>
        {profile:age}<hr>
    {/if}
{/profile}
```